# High Active Time and drop write speed after few seconds on RAID volume

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hardware-raid

I'm using RAID drive with Intel RS2BL040 on Windows-7-Pro-64x
The problem is, When I try to write to RAID drive,
The write speed is fall after few(about 6~7) seconds.
In case of reading, It's almost 150MB/s

[Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A98D8.png)

I tried to firmware update, driver update, re-insert every HDDs on the chassis
Also.. Windows re-install (The OS HDD located another controller)
But.. the result was same.

What should I check more beyond this? Please advise me.

I'm using MSI MS-7977 mainboard

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the HDD temperature with tools like HD Tune. Most likely it will either show nothing or a too high hdd temperature.

-> If the temperature is to high add a cooler.

The Intel card has 512 MB of RAM. If you write continously it can only support a few seconds of caching before it depends on the real speed of the HDDs.

The second step is therefore: which drives are you using?

Are they e.g. WD Green with high idle ssettings? -> tools like wdidle3 can be used. Parking in a raid can cause the raid to be marked as degred. with long rebuilds.

The other generic thing is: is only one program writting at a time or multiple ones. Repositioning while writing will slow down the performance drastically. Thinks like the downloader running in parallel.

Generic tip:
- use windows on a seperate disc

Comment: I'm using 16 HGST Ultrastar SATA 2Tb HDDs as raid 5 (1 spare) in Supermicro CSE-836BE16-R920B chassis

Comment: And I found the temperature of HDD is around 29~32 C